# Redibujar/Para cambiar impresión y dibuje pagina con contenido entera, no solo grafico

Tags: javascript, highcharts

¿Existirá alguna manera de modificar el código de Highcharts para, cuando selecciones la opción de descargar documento PDF te descargue no solo el grafico si no esa página entera donde se encuentra el grafico?

Answer (score -1):

A mi pregunta la respondo yo mismo, después de pasar varios días sin encontrar solución lo que hice fue utilizar la librería jspPDF,  tanto lo que necesitaba era exportar la pagina entera en pdf el grafico lo obtuve con canvas y utilice una Librería para controlar un error que me aparecía en ciertos navegadores como Internet Explorer, la librería a sido: canvg
y para dibujar el resto de la web con jspdf hice el resto.

Porque con la librería de highcharts no encontré como hacer esta operación y no se si existe actualmente.
Añado como fue que obtuve el grafico de manera correcta para que funcione en diferentes tamaños de pantallas a la hora de enviarlo al documento porque eso me dio muchos problemas y espero ayuden alguien más, esta fue mi solución:

```
 svg = $('div.myClase').highcharts().getSVG();
            canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvasIE = document.createElement('canvas');
            DOMURL =window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

            var img = new Image();
            canvg(canvas, svg);
            
            svgBlob = new Blob([svg], {  //creo el objeto blog con el svg para pasarle a la url
                type: 'image/svg+xml'
            });
            url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);//creo la url con el obj blog 

            img.onload = function () {
            //creo dos variables ancho y alto por defecto
                var w = 582;
                var h = 470;

               //al canvas le modifico el ancho y altura 
                canvas.width = w * 2;
                canvas.height = h * 2;
                
                //le agrego para que sea en px
                canvas.style.width = w + 'px';
                canvas.style.height = h + 'px';

                context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                setpixelated(canvas);

                context.scale(1.3, 1.3);

                context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 830, 760);

                //Liberando la memoria a medida que se dibuja en el lienzo
                DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
           
                    if (isIEBrowser()) { // Comprobación del navegador IE
                        canvg(canvasIE, svg);
                        dataUrl = canvasIE.toDataURL('image/PNG');
                    }
                    else{
                        dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    }

                    doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'png', 38, 310, 550, 220);//esta son las cordenadas x, y, w, h


                }
                img.src = url;


   function isIEBrowser(){
        var ieBrowser;
        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

          if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // Internet Explorer
          {
            ieBrowser = true;
          }
          else  //Otro navegador
          {
            //console.log('Otro navegador');
            ieBrowser = false;
          }

          return ieBrowser;
      }

    function setpixelated(context){
        context['imageSmoothingEnabled'] = false;       /* standard */
        context['oImageSmoothingEnabled'] = false;      /* Opera */
        context['webkitImageSmoothingEnabled'] = false; /* Safari */
        context['msImageSmoothingEnabled'] = false;     /* IE */
        context['imageSmoothingQuality'] = 'high';
      }
```

Librería canvg.js